# Angular2 input file onChange Event not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, events, angular, typescript

In Chrome and Internet Explorer my input file upload works fine, but I get an error when using in Firefox.

Extract from HTML Template

```
<input multiple style="display: none" type="file" (change)="onChange($event)" accept="image/*"/>
```

Extract from Component Class

```
  onChange(event: any) {

    let files = event.srcElement.files;
    ....
  }
```

The error message is just:
*TypeError: event.srcElement is undefined*

Is this a bug of Firefox? What is the meaning of the dollar sign?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using `event.target`(being used by other browser) because `srcElement` is only being used by IE. Thereafter you could `event.srcElement` as an fallback(for Internet Explorer case)

```
var target = event.target || event.srcElement; //if target isn't there then take srcElement
let files = target.files;
```

Comment: and Chrome. Thank you very much. That was fast.

Comment: @user59442 other browser does have `event.target`